# needed help for writing SQL query to generate expected output

Tags: sql

I am stuck in finding the expected output required for the below tables.I have attached the queries for both tables to go through the data and structure.

The issue is both the column name for items and sellers table has a same name column(NAME) so if I try to put join then i get an error of ambiguity

```
CREATE TABLE sellers (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  rating INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE items (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  sellerId INTEGER REFERENCES sellers(id)
);

INSERT INTO sellers(id, name, rating) VALUES(1, 'Roger', 3);
INSERT INTO sellers(id, name, rating) VALUES(2, 'Penny', 5);

INSERT INTO items(id, name, sellerId) VALUES(1, 'Notebook', 2);
INSERT INTO items(id, name, sellerId) VALUES(2, 'Stapler', 1);
INSERT INTO items(id, name, sellerId) VALUES(3, 'Pencil', 2);
```

How can we achieve expected output as mentioned below

```
Item      Seller
----------------
Notebook  Penny
Pencil    Penny
```

Comment: Hint : Use joins to achieve this

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: SELECT items.Name , sellers.Name
    FROM Items
    INNER JOIN sellers ON sellers.Id = items.SellerId

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
select a.id,a.name,b.name as seller
from
items a
left join
sellers b
on a.sellerid = b.id;
```

Let me know in case any clarifications are required.

Comment: Incase you want only seller to be 'Penny', use where b.name = 'Penny'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.name Item, s.name Seller
FROM items i
INNER JOIN sellers s ON s.Id = i.sellerId
WHERE s.name = 'Penny'
```

Use JOINs.